# Understand regression coefficient in regard to p-value

Tags: regression, p-value, interpretation, regression-coefficients

When investigating how well a model performs, I have a look at the p-values of the involved terms, among other things.

Now I wonder about the following: There is a term that has the highest coefficient (~20 and the next highest has ~14) but this coefficient doesn't have a significant p-value though it provides the highest regression coefficient.

How do I have to understand this? How do I separate between the meaning of the coefficients and their assigend p-value?

Comment: The features might have a different variance. Standardizing the features will likely tell a more direct story. Also take care that collinearity has an effect on the coefficient size. If the features are uncorrelated then the coefficients are easy to interpret.

Comment: Thanks, the variables are already standardized. Is there a hint why they shouldn't be? In general: Should high coefficients provide significant p-values? Is that, in return, correlated?

Comment: Look at confidence intervals. If the highest coefficient doesn't have a significant p-value, then its confidence interval has a negative lower bound and a positive upper bound, i.e. you can't exclude the possibility that its 'true' value is zero.

Comment: The key is in the multicollinearity, because when all explanatory variables are orthogonal and standardized, there will be the expected one-to-one, monotonic correspondence between the magnitudes of the estimated coefficients and their p-values. You can construct helpful examples with three variables: make the second variable orthogonal to the other two and give the third variable more or less correlation with the first variable (having the highest coefficient) and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, second whuber, multicollinearity also has an effect on the size of the confidence intervals of the coefficients.